# file provisioner in terraform giving timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 ec2 machines and I trying to copy the id_rsa.pub file from one to another. I am using ssm agent to connect.

```
resource "aws_instance" "ansible_master" {
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  ami           = "ami-0e1d30f2c40c4c701"
  tags = {
    Name = join("-", [var.env_name, var.project_name, "master"])
  }
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.ansible_instance_profile.name
  subnet_id            = aws_subnet.ansible_public_subnet.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id]
  user_data            = filebase64("templates/xxx.tpl")
  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.ansible_slave
  ]
   provisioner "file" {
    source      = "/home/ssm-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
    destination = "/home/ssm-user/.ssh/authorized_keys"

    connection {
        type = "ssh"
        user = "root"
        host = "${aws_instance.ansible_slave.private_ip}"
        private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
    }
  }
}
```

the error is

```
Error: file provisioner error

   with aws_instance.ansible_master,
   on ec2.tf line 30, in resource "aws_instance" "ansible_master":
   30:    provisioner "file" {
 timeout - last error: dial tcp 10.10.1.28:22: i/o timeout
```

What could be the reason ? Is it because I am using ssm ? thoughts ?

Comment: Does this TF code run on one of the EC2 instances? If not, where does it execute?

Comment: @Marcin yes, the provisioner code is running on the ec2 and then trying to copy the file to another ec2.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Any solution you got @Judi?